# Mark as Sold Ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attribute

I am trying to implement a button 'Sold' for user if he/she sold the item. What I have in mind on trying to implement this is to add a new column to my product's table. And if it is sold, I will then need to update attribute of the data. If referring to this link, http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes

This is something that I should do? Am I right?

model/product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sold
end
```

product controller

```
def sold
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @product.sold = 'true'
  save
  redirect_to product_path
end
```

views/products/show

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Sold', idontknowwhatotputhere %></button>
```

This also relate to what I am unsure with. What should I put at the link_to? and also how do I tell my application to relate to the def sold I have stated earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a couple things here.

1. Don't do special actions in the controller unless you have a good reason to do so.  All you are doing is updating a product.  So name the route 'update'.  And then in the link just do a put request with the sold=true.  Keeps things RESTful and conventional.
2. Once you do that, in your controller you will want to do validation and such.

   ```
   def update
     if product && product.update(product_params)
       redirect_to product_path
     else 
       redirect_to edit_product_path
     end
   end

   private

   def product
     @product ||= Product.find(params[:id])
   end

   def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(:sold)
   end
   ```

3.To add the link in your application to update it will be something like this.

```
<%= link_to 'Mark as sold', product_path(@product, product: {sold: true} ), method: :put %>
```

Comment: Okay.. I know this sounds stupid. How do I actually at the link do a put request with sold = true? Can you give an example of it? Sorry for my questions because I just recently learned RoR on my own. Actually by referring to your codes above, currently I do have the products#update because it is generated by scaffold. So Product has a edit page separately to update the price and so on. But I want the button to update automatically without having to direct to the product edit page i mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your first need to declare the route, something like this in routes.rb :

```
resources :products do

  get :sold, on: :member

end
```

then that route should generate a path helper like 'sold_product' and you can use it like:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Sold', sold_product(@product.id) %></button>
```

you can check the helpers using 'rake routes'

about update the attribute, you can use:

```
 @product.update_attribute(:sold, true)
```